# What Error: Provide a qualified name of a function, class or module" mean?

Tags: pycharm, python-unittest

I'm trying to execute unit tests using unittest library, but when a click on execute button, an error is displayed on Pycharm to me.

[Pycharm error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjqB.png)

My code:

```
class Secao20Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_comer_quiabo(self):
        self.assertEqual(comer('quiabo', True), 'É saudável')

    def test_comer_pizza(self):
        self.assertEqual(comer('pizza', False), 'Não é saudável')

    def test_comer_pizza_none(self):
        self.assertEqual(comer('pizza', None), 'Não é saudável')

    def test_dormir_ok(self):
        self.assertEqual(dormir(7), 'Boa noite')

    def test_dormir_nao_ok(self):
        self.assertEqual(dormir(6), 'Durma mais')

    def test_dormir_nao_ok(self):
        self.assertEqual(dormir('a'), 'Durma mais')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your target starts with a digit. I don't think it is allowed

[image]